# Schedule a Cron Job to start immediately when web application is deployed

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger, servlet-listeners

I am working on writing  a Job when my application is deployed. This Job should run every 5 mins and it should start immediately. But the problem is it is starting 5 mins after the deployment and repeating for every five minutes. Please help me with the changes required to start it immediately when the application is deployed.

```
 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        logger.info("contextInitialized() ,Starting instantiating Processor Engine");
        try{
        JobDetail job = newJob(MyServiceProcessor.class).withIdentity(
                "CronQuartzJob", "Group").build();
        Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("TriggerName", "Group").withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/5 * * * ?")).build();
        scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        }
        catch (SchedulerException e) {
            logger.error(", contextInitialized() ,Problem in starting Processor Engine"+e);
    }
```

Comment: which server and framework you are using for web application??

Comment: Hi! If one of the answers below helped you solve your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted, so your question appears as answered, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think in that way you can't start the job immediately. The cron-expression triggers each 0 or 5 minutes.

Alternative you could instantiate the job additionally and execute it manually in the contextInitialized(), if you dont need the JobExecutionContext.

```
MyServiceProcessor mjob = new MyServiceProcessor();
mjob.execute(null);
```

Comment: `"The cron-expression triggers each 0 or 5 minutes"` That's not how cron syntax works. `0/5` means "every five minutes starting at minute zero". Besides, directly calling `execute()` means you're overriding the Scheduler: no overlapping control, no interrupting, no trace of the job if you call `getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()`, no info about last execution or elapsed time...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `CronTrigger` for such simple scheduling. Use `SimpleTrigger` instead:

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("TriggerName", "Group")
        .withSchedule(SimpleTriggerBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInMinutes(5)
                    .repeatForever())
        .build();
```

This will schedule your job to fire right now, and then every 5 minutes.

For more uses of `SimpleTrigger` you can read [Quartz's tutorial on it](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05.html).